# C++ Map<Vertex*,Position> and using MAP.FIND with real vertex compare

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

I used the STL map in order to keep information about my vertices and their value
and I have decided to keep them as pointers for faster run time.

The problem is that now I'm trying to add new vertices only if they don't exist, therefore I used
the MAP.FIND() function and logically its not the right thing to do.
(since the find function now only compares by the pointers values and not the vertex values)

Now after googling for a bit, I tried using the longer c-tor

```
struct classcomp {
    bool operator() (const Vertex* v1,const Vertex* v2) const
    {
        return v1->getX()==v2->getX() &&
               v1->getY()==v2->getY() &&
               v1->getZ()==v2->getZ();
    }
};
map<Vertex *,Position,classcomp> ;
```

but still no success , what am I doing wrong?
is it even possible to use find in a different way than comparing pointer address values?

Thanks,
-Despair

updates: still having a problem, 
since you cant really use bool operator< with 2 arguments inside a struct.
so far I didnt find anything useful and all compilation tryouts failed.
couldnt find an example of doing so.
are you positive its possible with pointers?

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison function needs to impleent a strict weak ordering (`operator<`) not equality.

Comment: I tried inserting the strict weak ordering function inside the vertex class and use it as a compare (since it needs to get only 1 operand) but i get errors in the xutility includes and i get
the following ERROR :
\xutility(650): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments